# Dynamic cast to a custom class in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

In NewTaskViewController.h, delegate was declared to be a property of type id.
Does the typecast below make delegate point to the object of type ViewController?

```
#import "NewTaskViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation NewTaskViewController

- (IBAction)saveTask:(id)sender {
    if ([self.textField.text length] == 0)
        return;

    ViewController *tasksListView = (ViewController *)self.delegate;
    [tasksListView.tasks addObject:self.textField.text];

    [self close:sender];
}

- (IBAction)close:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Comment: "Point to a class"? What does that mean? Surely the delegate is **not** a class, just an object...

Comment: if you want your delegate to be a `ViewController` just declare it as such. tho you are bending the delegate pattern by using a specific class (instead of protocol) for delegate (wether or not it is declared that way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast tells the compiler that you want to use the `delegate` object as if it were a `ViewController`.  If it really is one, you're OK.  If it's not, bad things will happen at run-time.  That is, the cast doesn't do any kind of conversion.

Comment: And it's even unnecessary, since `id` is implicitly assignment-compatible with any Objective-C object type.

Comment: True, though the cast gets you some completion help from Xcode...and some style points for being explicit.  :)

Comment: Since `tasksListView` is already of type `ViewContoller *`, a cast is not needed for autocompletion to work. Furthermore, casts are ugly, they decrease readability, so there isn't even stylistic advantage to the cast.